# Send JavaScript Array to webhook

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord, send

I am trying to get data from an API, push the fetched data to an array and then send (post) that array with the data in a webhook. I tried `description: data,`, but it doesn't work. Can someone help me or is it even possible with js?

```
const api = "http://ip-api.com/json/"

    var ipinfo = [

    ]

    async function getIP() {
        const response = await fetch (api)
        const data = await response.json();
        const { city, zip, country, countryCode, lat, lon, org, query, region, regionname, timezone } = data;

        ipinfo.push(data);
        console.log(ipinfo)
    }

    getIP();

    
    function sendMessage() {
        fetch(
            'WEBHOOK URL', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify ({
                    allowed_mentions: {
                        parse: ['users', 'roles'],
                },
                // embeds to be sent
                embeds: [{
                    title: 'New IP logged',
                    description: "ipinfo" + ipinfo,
                    },
                ],
                }),
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting in the console/network tab? Or is it just 200OK?

Comment: I am getting an Error 400

Comment: That's a bad request, so I presume you're not sending the data in the format that is expected by the API or your request is in other way malformed. Since we don't know what you're calling it's hard to help. Is that DiscordAPI? If so what service are you calling? Have you read the documentation on what you should be sending and where?

Comment: No, if i dont put an array into the description, it works.

Comment: It depends on the API, if it doesn't allow certain inputs the you can't use them obviously. Does the API allow for arrays as description? Should it work?